# How come external hard drive causes fuzziness on the screen?

Tags: hard-drive, display, hardware-failure

I am connecting my external hard drive, HDD 640 GB, to my computer with an attached device that needs a power source and USB output. After connection established, my screen starts to get fuzzy, even over time fuzziness increases. However, it does not happen with 32 GB USB drive. By the way, I tried two different USB sockets to see if it is related with socket.

It doesn't seem to be causing a problem for now, but I wonder how connecting HDD from USB socket affects the screen. Could there be a problem in my motherboard? What I am asking is that what could be the possible reasons for this to happen?

Edit:

Model of HDD is Western Digital, SATA / 64 MB Cache, WD6400AARS. The data on it is 04 FEB 2010. Voltage direct current for HDD is, 5VDC : 0.70A and 12VDC : 0.55A.

There is a device that I use that I connect to my HDD, and that small device has USB 2.0 output and power output and I connect an AC/DC adaptor to that, and model of the adaptor is DM1220, INPUT:AC 100-240V 50/60Hz and OUTPUT: 12V-2A.

Comment: You mention a "power source". If that is an external power adapter, perhaps that is causing electrical interference. Please would you [edit] your question to give us a link to your external hard drive model so that we can see what alternative to suggest to check that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I thinks so too, but is there an other way for HDD to start? It needs external adapter. Or is there a way to compensate the interference? Can interference cause damage?

Comment: Do you have another 12V power adapter, rated at at least 2A, that you could try? It would also be worth checking using a different mains socket, as if there is a poor connection there then it could arc, which will cause electrical interference.